# Signature Generate by Honeyd “Honeycomb” is not accept by Snort IPS

Tags: kali-linux, snort, honeypot

I posted this on SO [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44652014/signature-generate-by-honeyd-honeycomb-is-not-accept-by-snort-ips] is this on topic here? What would I need to do to my question ?

I am doing a project which need to use "Honeyd" and "Honeycomb" plugin in pcA. So pcB will act as an attacker to attack the honeypot and Honeycomb will generate the Snort rule for snort help to block the same attack. However, currently after I put the signature that generate by Honeycomb to Snort I not able to run Snort as screen shot below [screenshot problem to launch Snort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6ede.png)

Below is the signature generate by Honeycomb

## Signature report at Wed Jun  7 17:40:37 2017

alert tcp 0.0.0.0/8 0 -> any 0 (msg: "Honeycomb Wed Jun  7 17h40m36 2017 "; ip_proto: "ip"; flags: FSRPAU!; flow: stateless; )

## Signature report at Wed Jun  7 17:44:47 2017

alert tcp 0.0.0.0/8 0 -> any 0 (msg: "Honeycomb Wed Jun  7 17h40m36 2017 "; ip_proto: "ip"; flags: FSRPAU!; flow: stateless; )
alert tcp any 0 -> any 0 (msg: "Honeycomb Wed Jun  7 17h44m45 2017 "; ip_proto: "ip"; flags: F+; flow: stateless; )
alert tcp any 0 -> any 0 (msg: "Honeycomb Wed Jun  7 17h44m45 2017 "; ip_proto: "ip"; flags: FP; flow: stateless; )
alert tcp any 0 -> any 0 (msg: "Honeycomb Wed Jun  7 17h44m45 2017 "; ip_proto: "19"; flags: FP; ack: 2417186313; flow: stateless; )
alert tcp any 0 -> any 0 (msg: "Honeycomb Wed Jun  7 17h44m45 2017 "; ip_proto: "19"; flags: F+; ack: 2417186313; flow: stateless; )
alert tcp any 0 -> any 0 (msg: "Honeycomb Wed Jun  7 17h44m45 2017 "; ip_proto: "ip"; flags: FSRPAU!; flow: stateless; )

## Signature report at Wed Jun  7 17:45:57 2017

alert tcp 0.0.0.0/8 0 -> any 0 (msg: "Honeycomb Wed Jun  7 17h40m36 2017 "; ip_proto: "ip"; flags: FSRPAU!; flow: stateless; )
alert tcp any 0 -> any 0 (msg: "Honeycomb Wed Jun  7 17h44m45 2017 "; ip_proto: "ip"; flags: F+; flow: stateless; )
alert tcp any 0 -> any 0 (msg: "Honeycomb Wed Jun  7 17h44m45 2017 "; ip_proto: "ip"; flags: FP; flow: stateless; )
alert tcp any 0 -> any 0 (msg: "Honeycomb Wed Jun  7 17h44m45 2017 "; ip_proto: "19"; flags: FP; ack: 2417186313; flow: stateless; )
alert tcp any 0 -> any 0 (msg: "Honeycomb Wed Jun  7 17h44m45 2017 "; ip_proto: "19"; flags: F+; ack: 2417186313; flow: stateless; )
alert tcp any 0 -> any 0 (msg: "Honeycomb Wed Jun  7 17h44m45 2017 "; ip_proto: "ip"; flags: FSRPAU!; flow: stateless; )

Comment: You are essentially trying to use rules generated by software which got no updates for 10 years (honeyd, honeycomb) against actively maintained software with regular releases and which got lots of changes in the last 10 years (snort). Thus, it is not really a surprise that  it does not work. Try running the rules with a  release of snort from 10 years ago instead.

Comment: Thanks you for your suggestion . Its true I never think about this.